# Which binding I can use to make sessions and secure connection with ssl?

Tags: c#, wcf, mono

I'm doing application in mono using wcf.

Which binding I can use to make sessions and secure connection with ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WCF service instance can be set to support a session by setting the InstanceContextMode to PerSession (this is changed on the service behavior tag.) SSL is supported by webhttpbinding.